# Creating WCF objects using Activator.CreateInstance

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a silverlight application with a service reference back to a Silverlight-Enabled WCF service. When I try to "new up" the WCF objects I get an exception about not having a constructor when I do the following.

```
Activator.CreateInstance(type, true);
```

However; this works:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code does not have the appropriate `ReflectionPermission` bit (presumably `ReflectionPermissionFlags.RestrictedMemberAccess`) then the underlying reflection search for non-public members will bomb out.

`RestrictedMemberAccess` is a *very* powerful permission and likely isn't granted to any code running in a browser, with the possible exception of an assembly reflecting over itself and/or anything granted by `InternalsVisibleToAttribute`.  Accessing private members of the Silverlight runtime libraries, for example, is prohibited by default policy.